# Adding groups to django app

Tags: django

I'd like to add the capability for users to create their own groups and invite others to join the group (or leave the group) or for users to request access to a group to a django app.

The group in this case is basically a pool of potential players for a football match, from which the actual players will be chosen.

Is the standard django auth groups system the correct thing to use here or is there another way? I'd need it to be able to do invitations and stuff, obviously.

I can obviously write my own but is there another app out there that already does this kind of thing nicely?

If not, has anyone got any tips on how to go about this?

Answer (score 0):

Creating your own model will give you more control to add extra information to those groups, such as the invitation system you described. The auth groups models was designed for classifying users by what level of control they have over the data on the website, which isn't what you want a groups model for. A new model will be much easier for you work with than trying to extend the existing groups model; which has built in functionality that you won't use, and probably has security features that will make it difficult to work with.

Comment: I tend to agree. So do you have any suggestions on how to do the invitations to groups side of things at all? I've never implemented something like that so I'm not entirely sure where to begin.